# C++ Memory Allocator

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to figure out how I could make a linked list which links to a single byte array. So each element I put into the byte array could be enqued() and dequeued(). However, I need to figure out how to do this using pointer offsets and linked lists.

My question is:
How do I get an offset of a set amount from the start of a pointer? For example, let's say the beginning of my list is at one pointer. I would start by just checking if that space is empty, if not, get the next value in the list. How do I offset from a current pointer position and get a new pointer location that is basically just an offset of another pointer, forward or backwards, up or down, left and right, plus or minus.

Someone asked for an example:

```
byte myData[1024];
```

I have to store all of my data into this. This is for a class assignment. Essentially, I have to use this array to store any and all of my data to it, and basically create a queue, like the standard c++ queue. I have to create Enqueue() and Dequeue() functions and then dynamically allocate the memory for each. I have a general idea of what I'm doing. I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to take a pointer of my current position, and then set it to a new position, and then have that be my "next" in the list.

Comment: What is a single byte array? You mean `char singlebytearray[1];` ? **Please provide some [MRE] in your question, so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61752636/edit) it.** Refer to [this C++ website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/) or to the [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) C++ standard.

Comment: Also explain why you are forbidden to use standard [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and explain what is your target architecture. An hypothetical [i286](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286) or an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) is quite different of a [RISC-V](http://riscv.org/) ( or an  [IBM Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Z) mainframze, and you find C++ compilers (e.g.  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) for both

Comment: Basile, I added some more information. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: You should read books like [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) and some [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book. Also read some [*textbook on operating systems*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and of course read the [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) C++ standard. Answering your question requires a full book, and we don't have time to write one just for you.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's that difficult. My friend said it's pretty easy.

Comment: There is a wikipedia page on [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and you can study the source of many opensource C++ implementations, including [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Of course, you'll need months of work. But **StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* website**

Comment: Notice that C++ already has a memory allocator, and you can customize your own. Read about `::operator new`  and `malloc`. Indeed, you need to read much more. Google, or your favorite web search engine, is your friend.

Comment: (I taught these things at University - perhaps to students of your age -, and there are *lots* of online resources ....)... Recommendation: read [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and find on [github](https://github.com/) some code similar to what you want

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to write me any code. I'm asking a very basic question:

How do I take a pointer to a memory address, and offset that pointer up or down an amount based on the size of whatever I give it (for example an integer). Are you saying this is complex and requires reading of multiple books to do?

Comment: Linked list, or array list? You mention both, but they are very different things. To answer your comment, just add or subtract from the pointer. That should have been covered when pointers were. I think the problem is you're throwing out a lot of very complex concepts (allocators, memory offsets) when you just want pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Hey sweenish, that sounds like exactly what I'm thinking about. When you subtract or add from a pointer, do the two things you add return a new pointer?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is pointer arithmetic. It's simple enough.

```cpp
std::int32_t foo[] = {42, 350};
std::int32_t* intPtr = &foo;  // We'll say foo is at address 0x005

++intPtr;  // Or intPtr += 1, either way the value of intPtr is now 0x009
           // *intPtr would now give you 350.
           // Your program knows the type being pointed to, and bumps up the address
           // accordingly. In this case a 4-byte integer
```

When doing pointer arithmetic on a C-array, it's important to have checks in place to stop you going out of bounds on either side. However, I don't even think pointer arithmetic is necessary. If you're storing an array privately, simply using index access and tracking what index your list ends at is a lot simpler. You still have to do checks, but their easier checks.

You're also saying linked list, but describing an array list. They are two very different data structures. Your queue will be a lot easier to write if you write a separate array list class, and store an array list object in your queue instead or a raw array.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get an offset of a set amount from the start of a pointer?

**Read the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) about [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) arithmetic. Notice the [existence of `offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) in C++.**

If you have two `short*ptr1;` and  `short*ptr2;` pointers which contain a  valid address, you might code `ptr1 - ptr2`  or `ptr1 + 5` or `ptr2 - 3` (however, `ptr1+ptr2` is forbidden). The C++11 standard explains when that is valid (sometimes it is not, e.g. when `ptr2` is the `nullptr`). Notice also that in  general `&ptr1[3]` is the same as `ptr1+3` and `ptr2[-1]` is exactly `*(ptr2-1)` (when that makes sense).

Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, such as [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (and you will have one if you do pointer arithmetic carelessly: beware of [segmentation faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)).

Tools like [address sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), debuggers (such as [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)), [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) should be helpful to understand the behavior of your code.

Don't forget to enable warnings and debug info in your C++ compiler. Once your C++ code compiles without warnings, read [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Notice that GCC 10 adds some [static analysis abilities](https://www.ibenews.com/static-analysis-in-gcc-10/). And you could use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) (or develop your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)).

The [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) wikipage has a nice figure. The wikipage on [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)s could help you also.

I recommend reading a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) and then some [*introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

On [github](https://github.com/) or elsewhere you can find tons of examples of C++ code related to your question (whose terminology is confusing to non-native English speakers).

Academic papers about *memory shape analysis* (such as [this one](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-46423-9_1.pdf) or [that](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/60398/TR1505.pdf?sequence=1) one) contain figures which would improve your understanding. [Books](https://gchandbook.com/) or web [resources](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/411/14-spring/Readings/wilson92uniprocessor.pdf) about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) are also relevant.